# How to arrange key when remove some value?

Tags: php, arrays

If I have array and unset some value below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => oo
    [1] => bb
    [2] => dd
    [3] => zz
    [4] => gg
)
```

Unset some value

```
Array
(
    [0] => oo
    [2] => dd
    [4] => gg
)
```

It remain 3 key.Can I arrange key from 0 to 3 without use sort() function because I wannt not to sort key or item in array like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => oo
    [1] => dd
    [2] => gg
)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remake the array

```
$newAr = array(); // your array
foreach($ar as $one){
   $newAr[] = $one;
}
print_r($newAr)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this; my personal favorite is to use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array-merge) with no arguments, which will re-index the array.

Answer (score 1):

I often use:

```
$a = array_values($a);
```

for this.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [php.net arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) page:

```
The unset() function allows removing keys from an array. Be aware that the array 
will not be reindexed. If a true "remove and shift" behavior is desired, the 
array can be reindexed using the array_values() function.
```

So use:
`$your_reindexed_array = array_values($your_original_array);`